# VS 2022 ASP.NET Core 6 MVC run on the kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, kestrel

I want to use Kestrel to execute ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app.

When I add a new project without writing any code, just publish directly and use the command dotnet project name.dll, it will reply and tell me to open localhost:5000 and you can see the web page. This is no problem.

But when I tested the currently developed website and it ran normally on IIS, but after using the command dotnet project name.dll, it just stayed there and there was no reply at all.

I would like to ask how to debug Kestrel or see the log after execution?

Comment: If your server contains the dotnet core runtime, you could directly running the dll, by using the dotnet xxxxx.dll. You could reopen a new cmd window and test again.